# Android Device Monitor shows an empty File Explorer for my Emulator

Tags: android, android-studio

When I view my emulator in Android Device Monitor, the File Explorer doesn't show anything:

[image]

I've tried deleting the emulator and creating it from scratch, but nothing seems to work. Any help would be appreciatd.

Comment: I had the same issue with the latest Android version (you appear to be using version 24). You can try with an older Android version, it will work there.